# Google Playstore Uploading APK "Version __ is not served to any device configuration; "

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

For some reason, whenever I try and upload a new **APK** file to my App on the Google Play Marketplace, it says that the version before is "not served to any configuration", etc.

Also, under **ACTIONS**, when I click on *Delete* or *Move to Alpha*, it just says "Saving Draft" with the Android icon at the top of the page and never responds. When I try to refresh or press anything, "Saving Draft" turns red  and says "An Unexpected Error has Occurred."

After seriously considering the changes I made, I realize that this must be a glitch because I've done nothing wrong. I uploaded another **APK** which is identical to ones previously uploaded and that one got the same error which makes no sense according to the error message.

It either works on too many, works on the same or doesn't work on enough devices to match the previous one and yet still gives a dumb error.

I've already made a new app with the newest **APK**, but I would've liked to just keep adding onto the old one because it already has its history and installers.

Does anyone know why this is happening or can at least confirm that it's a glitch/happening to you too?

Comment: Can't you  deactivate 14 ?

Comment: @Sheldon I've tried and I think it did the same thing. Honestly, even if I could, I wouldn't want to risk having no APK working because I feel like something more dumb would happen.

Comment: Well I haven't seen this exact same thing before, but maybe you can't deactivate 14 because it is in use ? If deactivating 14 doesn't fix it, it should reactivate ok ... in my experience I find this stuff to be robust (now) if a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a glitch for a while that you couldn't `unpublish` anything, or delete the failed `APKs`. `Delete` versions 15 and 16, then `unpublish` version 14. Then, `reupload` version 16, if that's the one you want `published`.